# How to fix my mouse auto click?

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, mouse-click

My mouse buttons are auto clicked randomly, mostly right button.
 I have tried 3 new mice, all worked OK on other computers but auto clicked randomly on my laptop.
When i remove all external mice and disable my laptop touchpad, remove laptop touchpad driver, the problem still happens so i think this is a software problem.
 I have Windows Defender installed.
How can i fix this problem without re-installing windows OS?
 I am a computer programmer so i willing to try even most advanced solution like kernel debugging.

Comment: Have you tried scanning for viruses? Also have you considered trying some live linux distro to test the same mouse on the same laptop but different OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a hardware problem. My laptop is a dell latitude e6520 so it has 2 sets of mouse buttons. One for touch pad and one for a pointing stick at the middle of its keyboard. The set of buttons for pointing stick have auto clicked errors. So i disabled them by driver options and auto clicked problem was disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge.

First, it could be in conflict with other programs or applications. Try to use the mouse in clean boot. Refer to the following clean boot steps.
(1) Log on as administrator
(2) `Win+R` and type `msconfig`
(3) We will get the window of `System Configuration`
(4) Select `General` tab
(5) Select `Selective startup`, then uncheck `Load startup items`
(5) Then select `Services` tab.
(6) Check `Hide all Microsoft services` checkbox.
(7) Click `Disable all`
(8) Select `Startup tab`, and click `Open Task Manager`.
(9) Make sure that `Startup` tab is selected.
(10)On the selected tab, right-click each startup program one-by-one to disable them.
(11)Close `Task Manager` when done and go back on `System Configuration` box, click `OK`.
(12)Then restart the machine.

Second, scan your PC to see if there is any viruses.

Third, the system could have some problem, run the following two command to see if there is any system issue.
`DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`
`sfc /scannow`

Finally, try go to `Devices manager` and reinstall/update the mouse driver or USB driver.

Hope these can help you.